# C++ test scoring system program - vector subscript out of range error

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying to create a test scoring system program.

1. First ask for the number of questions in the test
2. Then asks for the correct answers for each question.
3. Ask for the number of students and process each student by asking for their name and then loop through the questions asking for the student's answer.
4. Score each question.
5. After the last question calculate the students score and display "Student 'insert student name' scored 10 out of 20 or 50%."
6. Repeat until all the students have been scored.

This is what I have so far & it works up until the point where I put in the student's answers. The names are dropping the first letter for some reason when it asks for their answers and after I enter them in I'm getting a "Vector subscript out of range" error.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I think I've been staring at it for too long.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int questions=0; 
char correctAns;
char studentAns;
int students=0;
double score = 0;
double final=0;
string studentName;
vector<char> stuAnsVec; // answers input by the students
vector<char> corrAnsVec; // correct answers
vector<string> studNameVec; //  student names
void quiz();
void output();
void calculate();


int main()

{
    std::cout << "How many questions would you like?" << endl;
    std::cin >> questions; // Gets the total number of questions

    for (int k = 0; k < questions; k++)
    {
        std::cout << "What is the answer for question " << k+1 << endl;
        std::cin >> correctAns; // Gets each answer
        corrAnsVec.push_back (correctAns); // stores the answer
    }

    std::cout << "How many students are there?" << endl;
    std::cin >> students; // Gets the total number of students

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {

        std::cout << "What is the name of student " << i+1<< "?"<< endl;
        cin.ignore();
        std::getline(cin, studentName); 
        studNameVec.push_back (studentName);
    }

    quiz();
    calculate();
    final = score/questions;

    output();


    return 0;
}

void quiz()

{ // This is the function to determine the student's answers
    for(int i = 0; i < students+1; i ++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < questions; k++)
            {
        std::cout << "\nWhat is " << studNameVec[i] << "'s answer for question " << k+1 << endl; 
        std::cin >> studentAns; // Gets the student's answer for the question
        stuAnsVec.push_back (studentAns); // Stores the answer in the vector
            }
        }

}


void calculate()
{ // This is meant to actually calculate student scores

    for (int i = 0; i < students+1; i++)
    {
        if (stuAnsVec[i] == corrAnsVec[i])

           score = (score + 1);
        else 
            score = --score;
    }
}

void output()
{ // My output function

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    { 
        std::cout << studNameVec[i] << " got " << score << " right out of " << questions << " total." << endl;
        std::cout << "The percentage for " << studNameVec[i] << " is ";
        if (final = 1)
            std::cout<< "100 \n";
        else
        std::cout << final << endl;

        system ("pause");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < students+1; i ++)
```

this is wrong
change it to

```
for(int i = 0; i < students; i ++)
```

Answer (score 0):

cin.ignore() is eating the first letter of your students name. 
And what BufBills said.

Comment: If I take out the cin.ignore() it doesn't let me enter a value for student 1's name. It throws out " What is the name of student 1? What is the name of student 2?"